# Concave quadratic function unbounded below

Tags: quadratic-programming, non-convex-optimization

$$f(x) = y^\top x - \frac{1}{2} x^\top Q x$$

where $Q$ is both symmetric and positive definite is shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33576/proving-quadratic-function-is-bounded-vector-input) to be bounded above. However, is the following proof correct for $f(x)$ being unbounded below?

Proof that $f(x)$ is unbounded below:

Since $Q$ is symmetric, the spectral theorem tells us that, $x^\top Q x \geq \lambda_{\min}(Q) \ x^\top x$, where $\lambda_{\min}(Q) > 0 $ is the smallest eigenvalue. However $x^\top Q x = \lambda(Q) \ x^\top x$ when $x$ is an eigenvector, since $Q x = \lambda(Q) x$.

In this case, there is a linear term in the quadratic equation; therefore, let $x = \alpha v$, where $v$ is the eigenvector associated with $\lambda_{\min}(Q)$, such that $\|v\|_2 = 1$ and $\alpha > 0$.
 Substituting $\alpha v$ in the original quadratic equation yields

$f(\alpha v) = \alpha y^\top v - \frac{\alpha^2 \lambda_{\min}(Q)}{2} v^\top v$, and since $\| v\|_2 = 1$, therefore,

$f(\alpha v) = \alpha y^\top v - \frac{\alpha^2 \lambda_{\min}(Q)}{2}$

now as $\alpha \rightarrow \infty$,  $f(\alpha v) \rightarrow -\infty$

Thank you.

Comment: You forgot to mensioned that the minimum eigen value is positive because of positive definiteness, but I agrre that it's obvious. Nice proof else.

Comment: Yes thank you, I added that piece of information